# Where am I creating multiple instances of DbContext? (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, controller, entity, dbcontext

I have the following structure of repositories:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DataContext context = null;

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Repository()
    {
        context = new DataContext();
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();

    }

    public Repository(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class PlayerpostRepository : Repository<PlayerPost>
{
    public PlayerpostRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class PlayerRepository : Repository<Player>
{

    public PlayerRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I create the instances like this:

```
private static DataContext db = new DataContext();
    private PlayerpostRepository repository = new PlayerpostRepository(db);
    private PlayerRepository playerrep = new PlayerRepository(db);
```

But when I call the `repository.SaveChanges()` method in the controller, I get the following error:

> entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Which, if I understand it correctly, means that I have created multiple instances of `DbContext` which are connected to one object. I don't see where that is happening.

Comment: Why you share the DataContext?

Comment: You're newing one up in the parameterless constructor then newing another one up and passing it in to the parameter constructor. Consider using an IoC container. http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Don't store your context as a static field in your controller. You risk erratic behaviors as it will be reused across requests. Your context shouldn't live longer than the processing of the HttpRequest

Comment: Steve Greene: I still don't see where that is happening. I'm only calling the parameterless constructor once, which creates the instance and then I'm passing the instance as a parameter in the other constructors. I will try the IoC.

jbl: What is the right way to handle DbContext in a Controller then?